# HTTPS protocol error (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I try to make https on my asp.net mvc website like this in web config

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to https">
      <match url="(.*)"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

But when I compile project on localhost I have this error

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxw1m.png)

On staging all okay.

Where is my problem?

Comment: Look in Chrome's console/security tab for the reason.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your rewrite rules.

Comment: Really? 

Has. Because  it happens when I write those rules @mason

Comment: You're missing the point. The rewrite rules are just switching your protocol to HTTPS. You can manually use an HTTPS url in your browser and get the same result. Therefore the rewrite rules aren't necessary to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have an SSL certificate locally to work with? Whereas your staging server probably does.

You can, however, create a Self-Signed Certificate to test SSL locally via IIS Manager. The browser will still throw a warning message, but you can ignore it when using self-signed certs for local development.

Regards

Craig